# Plot Circle On Google Maps V2 Based On User Input

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to draw a circle on a map based on the parameter entered by user.

For example, if user input a parameter of 1000 radius. Next thing to happen, when clicking the button "Plot", it will open up the Google Maps and draw an circle on it.

I have tried googled around for related tutorials. Unfortunately, all were teaching to tap on the map and draw the shape automatically where the radius has been defined in the source vs mine.

Following is my part of codes.

mapping.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#607D8B">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radius"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_span="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        <requestFocus />

    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#37474F"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Plot"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#37474F"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is my java file.

```
package com.epsilon.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LossActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText radius = null;
    Button plotButton = null;
    Button clearButton = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapping);

        radius = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);            
        plotButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        plotButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loss, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == plotButton) {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapActivity.class);
        //something to write overhere
        intent.putExtra("radius",radius);// playing with this
        this.startActivity(intent);                     
        }
        else if(v == clearButton) {
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");               
        }
    }

}
```

Lastly is the map activity of the google maps, I think the issue is I have less idea on how to related the java file above with another java file of this.

```
package com.epsilon.map;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    Marker marker;
    Circle shape;

    private double radius;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        SupportMapFragment mfrag = (SupportMapFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mfrag.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    private void setMarker(String locality, String country, double lat,double lng){

        LatLng LL = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .title(locality)
                .position(LL)
                //.icon(BitmapDescriptor.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mapmarker))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());

        marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);

        shape = drawCircle(LL);


    }

    private Circle drawCircle(LatLng LL) {

        CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions()
                .center(LL)
                .radius(radius)
                .fillColor(0x330000FF)
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                .strokeWidth(3);
        return googleMap.addCircle(options);
    }

    private void removeShape(){
        marker.remove();
        marker = null;
        shape.remove();
        shape = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you need to do is something like this:

In your `LossActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == plotButton) {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(radius.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
        //something to write overhere
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("radius", radius);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        this.startActivity(intent);                     
        }
        else if(v == clearButton) {
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText("");               
        }
    }
    .....
```

and then in your `MapActivity`:

```
private String provider;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private double radius;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            if (b.containsKey("radius")) {
                 radius = b.getDouble("radius");
            }
        }
        SupportMapFragment mfrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mfrag.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Here starts the old code
        //Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        //provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 5, this);
        //mCurrentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        //if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
        //      onLocationChanged(mCurrentLocation);
        //}         
    }

    // Part of the new code
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          setMarker("Locality", "Country", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude();
          locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
```

Also, turn on the GPS for better accuracy.

Comment: I was expecting upon inputting the radius, when the button is clicked, assuming it has to detect my location first, and once done it will plot the circle on the map

Comment: No errors at all, even tapping on the map shows nothing.

Comment: If I understood the problem, this edit should solve it... Please try the new solution and report if it works.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked.. However, the plotting is a little bit off. For example, my intention was to plot the radius exactly from my current position but it somehow placed the marker with the circle like 500m away from my location. I have turned on my GPS. Not sure if it is my phone problem.

Comment: Here is the picture. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8t7p99fxvnsj4k/2015-04-12%2016.14.29.png?dl=0

Comment: Glad it worked. Ok, try the new solution. This should get you the precise location, because in the previous solution, the error was probably with the `getLastKnownLocation` returning location that was 500m away...
Also, I am sorry because I'm throwing solutions like this, currently cannot test the solution, so I am typing from my head, the error are being made... :)

Comment: erm after the getLastKnownLocation was removed..i can't plot the radius again :-(

Comment: could you post the earlier code with the getLastKnownLocation again?

Comment: Ok, I edited one more time, this now should work correctly, if not, then I really need to get to my machine and solve the problem... Try this, it should get you the latest location and draw the circle...